# How do I pre-select specific values from a dynamically populated dropdown list for HTML form?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I have three drop down lists with identical options, all of which are populated from the database and works fine. I would like to implement a 'smart mapping' feature where the three fields are pre-selected based on conditions. Currently, the pre-selected option is the first value (i.e. Container ID) of the dropdown list. I would like the pre-selected options to be specific values instead as seen in the attached images.

Current pre-selected values:
[image: Image 1: Current pre-selected values]

Desired pre-selected values
[image: Image 2: Desired pre-selected values]

Dynamic dropdown list options
[image: Image 3: Dynamic dropdown list options]

**Python Code (Flask)**

```
# db_col is the list of the three labels of the HTML form
db_col = ['Container ID', 'Container Type', 'Date of Manufacture']

# df_list is the list of the six options available in the dropdown list
df_list = ['Container ID', 'Container Type', 'Unit', 'Year of Manufacture', 'Date of Manufacture', 'Age']

# smart_mapping is the list of the three pre-selected options for the label in order
smart_mapping = ['Container ID', 'Container Type', 'Date of Manufacture'] 

# smart_mapping_dict is the dictionary of the labels as keys and pre-selected options as values
smart_mapping_dict = {'Container ID': 'Container ID', 'Container Type': 'Container Type', 'Date of Manufacture': 'Date of Manufacture'}
```

**HTML Form (Jinja Template)**

```
<form class="uploadDataForm" action="/mapping2/{{ id }}" method = "POST">

{% for fetchcol in db_col %}

    <label for="{{ fetchcol }}">{{ fetchcol }}</label>
    <select class="form-select" name="{{ fetchcol }}" id="fetchcol{{ loop.index }}" onclick="changeColumnCol{{ loop.index }}(this.value)" >

        {% for ex_col in df_list %}
            <option value="{{ ex_col }}">{{ ex_col }}</option>
        {% endfor %}

    </select>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="/second_page/{{ id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Discard Data Tape</a>
        <button class="btn btn-default nextBtn text-center ">Next</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have tried to search for similar questions and answers, but they require the use of javascript and/or php methods, both of which I'm unfamiliar with and hence unable to adapt to my issue. How do I get my HTML form to pre-select desired options as shown in Image 2?

Edit: Desired options are usually not be the same name as labels i.e. 'Date of Manufacture' label could correspond to 'Age' option instead for the smart mapping feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by making use of Jinja's `if` statement. Basically, we check if the current option is equal to the corresponding value in the `smart_mapping_dict`. If so, we add the attribute `selected` to the HTML `<option>` tag to pre-select it.

```
<form class="uploadDataForm" action="/mapping2/{{ id }}" method = "POST">

{% for fetchcol in db_col %}

    <label for="{{ fetchcol }}">{{ fetchcol }}</label>
    <select class="form-select" name="{{ fetchcol }}" id="fetchcol{{ loop.index }}" onclick="changeColumnCol{{ loop.index }}(this.value)" >

        {% for ex_col in df_list %}
            {% if ex_col == smart_mapping_dict[fetchcol] %}
                <option value="{{ ex_col }}" selected>{{ ex_col }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{{ ex_col }}">{{ ex_col }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    </select>
    <br>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="/second_page/{{ id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Discard Data Tape</a>
        <button class="btn btn-default nextBtn text-center ">Next</button>
    </div>

</form>
```